# Set object properties at constructor call time (PHP)

Tags: php

I wonder if it's possible to achieve similar functionality to C#'s compact instantiation syntax:

```
itemView.Question = new ItemViewQuestion()
{
  AnswersJSON = itemView.Answer.ToJSONString(),
  Modified = DateTime.Now,
  ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name
};
```

I wish to be able to create an object of arbitrary class passing their properties without having to set up constructor code for these properties.

To put up another example, this can be done with `stdClass` like this:

```
(object) ["name" => "X", "age" => 30]
```

Type juggling does not work for custom classes, however.

Comment: You might want to clarify what that C# example does exactly, PHP users won't be familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such functionality natively in PHP, unfortunately.

But you can create a class in your project and extend it in the classes you wish to instantiate without a constructor. Something like this:

```
<?php

class Fillable{
    public static function fill($props)
    {
        $cls = new static;
        foreach($props as $key=>$value){
            if (property_exists(static::class,$key)){
                $cls->$key = $value;
            }
        }
        return $cls;
    }
}
class Vegetable extends Fillable
{

    public $edible;
    public $color;
}

$veg = Vegetable::fill([
    'edible' => true,
    'color' => 'green',
    'name' => 'potato' //Will not get set as it's not a property of Vegetable. (you could also throw an error/warning here)
]);

var_dump($veg);
```

Checkout [this fiddle](https://ideone.com/ab0wAX) for the working example

Comment: I am aware that potatoes are not vegetables.

Comment: The OP may won't be able to change the class in question. In case it's from an external library, for example. Still, your answer is useful, but the implementation has to change a little bit: `Fillable` class becomes `FillableVegetable extends Vegetable`, and then `$veg = FillableVegetable::fill( ... )`. Does it make sense?

Comment: In order to make this available to all classes, including from external libraries, he could use the [scalar_objects](https://github.com/nikic/scalar_objects) extension. I think you can extend classes with it. It's like javascript's prototypes.

Comment: And doesn't really need to be `FillableVegetable`. In this example, the `Fillable` class's `fill` function will accept and fill any class that extends it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Depending on the number of classes in their app, it's annoying writing every `Fillable*` class as I suggested.

Comment: Unless you have some tool to compose those classes automagically XD

Comment: This might work as a pretty clean alternative. You say, it would've been great not having to use inheritance everywhere, but maybe I don't even have to. I can definately apply this for certain parts of the project.

Comment: I think it's always nice to have all your classes inherit a single class depending on your project needs, because it's possible that many classes might have some common functions (like fill, in this case)

Answer (score 0):

This is valid in PHP though:

```
<?php
    class Demo {

        public function getA() {
            return $this->Options['A'];
        }

    }

    $D = new Demo();
    $D->Options = Array(
        'A' => '1',
        'B' => '2',
        'C' => '3'
    );

    var_dump($D->getA());
```

Or, something like this:

```
<?php
    class Demo {

        public function __construct($Options) {
            $this->Options = $Options;
        }

        public function getA() {
            return $this->Options['A'];
        }

    }

    $D = new Demo(Array(
        'A' => '1',
        'B' => '2',
        'C' => '3'
    ));


    var_dump($D->getA());
```

Or even this:

```
<?php
    class Demo {

        public function __construct($Options) {
            foreach ($Options as $key=>$value) $this->$key = $value;
        }

        public function getA() {
            return $this->A;
        }

    }

    $D = new Demo(Array(
        'A' => '1',
        'B' => '2',
        'C' => '3'
    ));


    var_dump($D->getA());
```

I guess it really depends what are you trying to achieve? You said you do not want to use magic functions or setters, but is there more to it?

Comment: OP asked for a way of doing this without `__construct`

Comment: @Phiter Actually, he actually said "without constructor code for these properties", so one could assume that he does not want to initiate every variable in the constructor, perhaps because he does not know all variables in advance?

Comment: True! I didn't pay attention. I think you could make use of `property_exists` in your approach in case OP has manually set the properties for the class.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously php doesn't have this. Somewhere a function is required. I did an implementation using a trait which is close.

```
<?php

Trait Init {
    public function init($arr) {
        $vars = get_object_vars($this);
        foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
            if ( array_key_exists($k, $vars) ) $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
}

class Demo {
use Init;
    public $answersJSON;
    public $modified;
    public $modifiedBy;
}

$obj = new Demo();
$obj->init(['modified' => 'now']);

print_r($obj);
```